# A function that adds a string ending to each member in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to create a JS function that adds a string ending to each member in an array. The expected function when called should return something like this:

```
addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly")
```

Expected output:

```
["cleverly", "meekly", "hurriedly", "nicely"]
```

Thanks for all answers suggesting to use `map` method, but I want to use a `for` loop, here is what my code looks like:

```js
const addEnding = (arr, str) => {
  let result = '';
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result = arr[i]
    result += str
  }
  return result
}

console.log(addEnding(["new", "pander", "scoop"], "er"))
```

The issue is that it only returns the first element of an array, when I expect it to return all elements from array + str ending

Comment: Using **map()** method returns a new array, it does not modify the existing one. It is better to use for/forEach loops if you are looking to update the exisiting array. Check my answer as well.

Comment: In your case the little mistake you did is, you used **result** variable and updated that. Use `arr[i] = arr[i] + str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the result as a string and replace it over the iteration. Just change the data type to `array` as you expected.

```js
const addEnding = (arr, str) => { 
  let result = '' // You initiated a string as a result not an array
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    result = arr[i]  // The string got replaced every time it interate
    result += str 
  } 
  return result // The result is always the last item
} 
console.log(addEnding(["new", "pander", "scoop"], "er"))
```

```js
const arr =["new", "pander", "scoop"]
const str = 'er'

const addEnding = (arr, str) => { 
  let result = []; // Init an array as format output
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arr[i] + str  // assign like this
  } 
  return result 
} 
console.log(addEnding(arr, str))
```

Answer (score 1):

use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, which will iterate over your array and return a new array with the modified version of each.

Using string interpolation you can append easily the suffix

```js
function addEnding(arr, end) {
  return arr.map(word => `${word}${end}`);
}

console.log(addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly"))
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly with map method! Although I am having issues when trying to use traditional for loop..

Comment: for traditional foor loop check Shohel answer. It all depends if you want your code to be more declarative or imperative. For readability, map is usually a better option. Keep in mind also that map function generates a new array; with a for loop, although more imperative, lets you override the existing one without creating a new one

Comment: Here is my code: ```const addEnding = (arr, str) => {
  let result = '';
  
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    result = arr[i]
    result += str
  } return result
}
addEnding(["new", "pander", "scoop"], "er")
``` The issue is that it only returns first element of an array

Comment: do you want to return an array or a string?

Comment: if you want to return an array, then you just do `arr[i] += str`; no need of varaible result. And then just return the updated array. If you want to join all the words in the array, then use arr.join(' ')

Comment: Array + string ending for each array elements

Comment: if you want to use for loop, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486686/1437934) answer, if you want to use map function you can use mine

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following code

```js
function addEnding(array, suffix) {

  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = array[i] + suffix;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly"));
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! However, I'd like to write it without if statement, map method and push method; with just a simple for loop..

Answer (score 1):

```
function addSuffix(arr, suff){
    var newArr=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       newArr.push(arr[i] + suff);

    return newArr;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [String#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

```js
function addEnding(words, suffix) {
  return words.map(word => word.concat(suffix))
}

const output = addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use for loop and want to do this in a functional way (the way you choose) then you can try like this.

> I have executed the statements on **Node REPL**.
>
> **Note »** Using map() method returns a new array, it does not modify the existing one. It is better to use for/forEach loops if you are looking to update the exisiting array.
>
> **Your mistake:** In your case the little mistake you did is » you used **result** variable and updated that. Use `arr[i] = arr[i] + str`.

```
> const addEnding = (arr, str) => {
... arr.forEach((item, i) => {
.....     arr[i] = item + str;
..... })
... return arr
... }
undefined
> 
> addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly")
[ 'cleverly', 'meekly', 'hurriedly', 'nicely' ]
> 
> addEnding(["new", "pander", "scoop"], "er")
[ 'newer', 'panderer', 'scooper' ]
>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const addEnding = (arr, str) => {
    let result = []
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result[i] = arr[i] + str
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Hey @jonrodsanz, I see this is your first post. Great answer! It's also recommended to include a description of what was the solution and why, alongside the code. (you can edit your answer, no need to delete and re-create)

Answer (score 1):

```
function wordConverter(arr, str) {
    return arr.map(x => x.concat(str));
}

console.log(wordConverter(['clean', 'dye', 'dry', 'call'], 'ing'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` which will return a new array of words formed by concatenating words from original array and the suffix

```js
function addEnding(array, suffix) {
  // assuring input is array otherwise map will not work
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    return array.map(item => item + suffix)
  }
}
   console.log(addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const addEnding = (array, suffix) => array.map(word => `${word}${suffix}`);
const result = addEnding(["clever", "meek", "hurried", "nice"], "ly");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the below function if you want to use the traditional for loop.

```
function addEnding(arr, end) {
  for(let i=0; i<= arr.length-1; i++)
      arr[i] += end;
  return arr;
}
```